# How to crop a text that it can fit into a block-type tag?

Tags: php, html, text, tags

In my form I'm asking users to enter a text and then when they submit the form the text is sent to my database. When I query the entered text and I insert it into my html page it doesn't fit the container instead if a line has to many words it outputs the line in length. I'd like to know how can I do to crop the line if its size is way too much assuming the size of the container in which it reads. and oh ! to extend my request : what is the best way to treat user input and retrieve it in the exactly same format ??

Comment: It might help if you provided some examples.

Comment: To be more specific, I'm using a paragraph tag to output what the user writes in a form (textarea), the paragraph is styled with a display set to 'block' and a specified width; but if the user write a line too long (without returns) the line in my paragraph container is sliding over, I want the line to return automatically.

Comment: and to be more specific again, i'm coding a visitors' book for my website ! I don't wanna make the user upset :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to "crop" text you can simply use substr.

```
echo substr($string,0,150);
```

This will cut your string up to 150 chars

@OP: after reading your question. Did you mean the css ?

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Anyway even if you div is set to display:block; it shouldn't show the horizontal scrollbar

### Addendum

The problem with your link is that your div has the class `listing` with

```
white-space: pre;
```

you should change it

```
white-space: normal;
```

Comment: see the comment in my topic, i hope it'll make clear, again sorry I don't have the terms

Comment: @odda: there is some sort of other problem in your html/css because the text always goes on new line in a div (assuming of course it has some space between)

Comment: seems like it's not all the time the same

Comment: @odda: there is some problem with listing class, read my answer I have edited

Answer (score 0):

This is not a perfect solution, but you could do it like this:

```
$string = 'yourstring';

if (strlen($string) > TheMaxSizeOfYourString) {
    $string = substr($string, 0, TheMaxSizeOfYourString-3);
    $string .= '...';
}
```

This isn't perfect as the actual width of your string varies on the font you use.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem is. If you specify the maxlength of a text input, you'll always have  a set max length of your text.  Otherwise you can do substr($yourstring, 0, your_set_length). However simply setting maxlength makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

you can shorten text to a specific length and 'round' it to the nearest full word by using something like i've got below, and even have it add some trailing "..." if needed...

```
function ShortenText($text,$chars) {
        // Change to the number of characters you want to display
        $orig = $text;
        $text = $text." ";
        $text = substr($text,0,$chars);
        $text = substr($text,0,strrpos($text,' '));

        // Add ... if the text actually needs shortening
        if (strlen($orig) > $chars) {
            $text = $text."...";
        }
        return $text;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the only problem related to formating is the new lines then I would go like this:

1. User enters some text in text area.
2. I clean the text which is I remove all new lines, (also if you like remove tabs or multiple spaces).
3. Store the clean text in the database.
4. When the text will be retrieved then you output it in html page, if you place it inside a div then you don't have to worry because the text will break on its own.
5. If you need to show a preview of it you choose the substr as indicated above.

Conclusion I don't think that your request to get the text in excactly same format is a good idea (except that you have sth unusual-else in your mind). In contrast you want to clean the text that the user inserts. Hope I have understood correct what you are trying to do!

Comment: thanks Melsi but I finally kicked my trouble away ! I was using a <pre> tag that's why the line didn't rely on the paragraph's dimensions... And looking at the document definiton type I get told of the width attribute for the tag 'pre' really useful :D thanks anyway I take it to considerations